# How interface method called in c#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, interface, microsoft.extensions.hosting

I am working on .NET Core.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

The `CreateHostBuilder` method returns `IHostBuilder` interface and is calling the `Build` method of that.  So is it possible to implement code inside that interface or is it any design pattern?

Comment: I am unclear as to what you are asking. Can you reformat the question so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do? See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

CreateHostBuilder method return type which implement interface IHostBuilder and Build method on that returned type is getting called.

Comment: but we can't implement interface. then how we can call method of that interface?

Comment: @rushangpanchal: Consider a type you are familiar with, `System.String`. it implements `IComparable`. I can write code like `var s="abc"; var ic=(IComparable)s;`. At this point, the variable `ic` doesn't know it's referring to a string, only to an instance of some type that implements `IComparable`. Just like if it was set as the result of calling some function that returned `IComparable`. About the only thing I can do with `ic` is call `ic.CompareTo(something)`. It's still a string under the covers, but it's only `IComparable` from the `ic` point of view

Answer (score 0):

The class isn't sealed, but Build isn't virtual, so it is a bit of a challenge to extend it. But you can always wrap the object and implement the interface in the wrapper, passing through control or overriding or extending whatever behavior you want.

```
public class MyHostBuilder : IHostBuilder
{
    protected readonly IHostBuilder _inner;

    public MyHostBuilder(IHostBuilder inner)
    {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public IHost Build()
    {
        DoSomethingCustom();
        return _inner.Build();          //Do something custom then pass through
    }

    public void ConfigureContainer<TContainerBuilder>(Action<HostBuilderContext,TContainerBuilder> action)
    {
        _inner.ConfigureContainer(action);  //Pass through without extending
    }
}
```